# Bot Framework Test connection to your bot fails with status code Forbidden

Tags: botframework, botconnector

My bot works receives and sends messages fine in Slack, Skype and emulator.

However when I click the blue Test button in the bot portal (https://dev.botframework.com/) it gives me the error message "Authorization for Microsoft App ID my_id_is_replacedhere failed with status code Forbidden"

Full error is below.

I also get the same error when I send a scheduled message to Slack using endpoint https://slack.botframework.com/ and the  Conversations.SendToConversation() method. This used to work and the Test button used to succeed.

Why am I getting this message? Is there a NuGet pkg update that broke it? 
I went through the troubleshooting guide, but everything else seem to work.

Thank you

> InternalServerError { "message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "exceptionMessage": "Authorization for Microsoft App ID
>   my_id_is_replacedhere failed with status code Forbidden",
>   "exceptionType": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException", "stackTrace": "
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.d__19.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()\r\n at
>   Grasp.MessagesController.d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Code\Relegraph_Git\GraspThree\Grasp\Controllers\MessagesController.cs:line
>   55\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

Comment: I see there something like this: "my_id_is_replacedhere".
Have you tried to change that placeholder with your applicatoin's real ID?

Comment: Yes I have a real and working Microsoft App ID in my config files and in my error message. I just replaced here with "my_id_is_replacedhere" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what caused the error. Apparently the Test button in the bot portal sends a "Ping" message to the bot. In my MessagesController code I was trying to reply to every message with something like this:

> ```
>                         ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(Act.ServiceUrl), appcred);
>                         Activity reply = Act.CreateReply(replymsg);
>                         connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(reply);
> ```

However - when I do this for the Ping type of Activity (Activity.Type=ActivityTypes.Ping), then I get the above error. When I just ignore the Ping message, then the Test button works.

I still had an issue when I get the same error when sending messages to Slack on a schedule (no incoming message to reply to). I worked around that issue using Slack's WebAPI:

> https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token={0}&channel={1}&text={2}&as_user={3}

Answer (score 2):

Try use

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(notify.ServiceUrl, DateTime.MaxValue);
```

before

```
connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(...)
```