# Bot Framework bot can't post in Microsoft Teams channel without being prompted

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot built using the Microsoft Bot Framework, published in Azure App Service, that I want to post in a Microsoft Teams channel in response to a POST call. I have the following in a WebhookAPIController class, inheriting from ApiController:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/WebhookAPI")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RespondToWebhook([FromBody] PostTestModel value)
{
    try
    {
        await CreateChannelConversation(value.text);
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return resp;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }            
}

private async Task CreateChannelConversation(string value)
{
    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUrl"]));
    var channelData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    channelData["teamsChannelId"] = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelId"];
    IMessageActivity newMessage = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
    newMessage.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
    newMessage.Text = "Hello channel.";
    ConversationParameters conversationParams = new ConversationParameters(
        isGroup: true,
        bot: null,
        members: null,
        topicName: "Test Conversation",
        activity: (Activity)newMessage,
        channelData: channelData);
    var result = await connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParams);
}
```

This code gets the service URL and Channel ID from AppSettings; as far as I can tell, the channel ID never changes for a given Teams channel. However, when I make a POST call to (bot URL)/api/WebhookAPI, no message gets posted and I get this error message in response:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Authorization for Microsoft App ID [ID omitted] failed with status code Unauthorized and reason phrase 'Unauthorized'",
    "exceptionType": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.<CreateConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.<CreateConversationAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at WebhookTestBot.Controllers.WebhookAPIController.<CreateChannelConversation>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at WebhookTestBot.Controllers.WebhookAPIController.<RespondToWebhook>d__1.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).",
    "exceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()"
}
```

However, if I @-mention the bot in the channel first, the POST call returns 200 and the bot posts in the channel. Is there a way I can configure my bot to be able to post in the channel without being mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668651/5847190). Adding the following code to CreateChannelConversation() before the call to CreateConversationAsync() worked:

`MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUrl"], DateTime.MaxValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding credentials to the ConnectorClient constructor:

```
string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"];
string appPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"];
var appCredentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appId, appPassword);
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUrl"]), appCredentials );
```